# Spring boot controler response Json object

Tags: json, spring

I am new to spring boot and trying to learn it.
I tried the example with the RESTful service where one gets a JSON object from the controller
as response.
With the web address provided it works.
But when i run it against a local controller in a spring boot installation on tomcat i only get
a String array not a JSON object as response.
I know you need to have a JSON mapper class  in the project ( Jackson - mapper ).
But in the example its defined how to include that.
I looked here and at Google but found nothing about how to include the mapper.
Can someone tell me what  i must do to get a JSON object in the response body from the controller or where to look?
Any advise welcome.

Khelvan 
Code Controller

```
 @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    @ResponseBody
  public String ajaxGreetings(
    //  @RequestParam("name") String p_name
) {
    String json = "{\"id\":2488,\"content\":\"Hello!\"}";


    return json;
}
```

Ajax in Html

```
$.ajax({
   //     url: "http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting"
      url: "http://host.org:8080/greeting"
    }).then(function(data) {
       $('.greeting-id').append(data.id);
       $('.greeting-check').append(data);
       $('.greeting-content').append(data.content);
    });
```

Any Advise what is missing?

Thanks and best regards

Khel

Comment: Please provide some code that you used as well as a clear case which did not work

Comment: Please post the code for your controller and spring context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Its necessary to retrun a java Class containing the data as attributes from the controller not a json String. Spring convertes the return to json format and does only funtions when one returns a class here.

Best regards.

Khel.